# How to find max k elements in array?

Tags: matlab

For example I have 1D array and I want to find k max elements in array and return their values and\or indexes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`sort()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/sort.html), and then take the first `k` elements of the result.

Comment: you're right. I must be confusing it with some other function. Sorry!

Comment: Yes, you right but I need indexes too.(sorting violating the order of indexes)

Comment: @mrgloom: take another look at the documentation I linked to; you can get the indices from `sort`.